# Is there a way to call a method on all instances of an interface?

Tags: c#

i have an interface which is implemented by different classes.

```
public interface foo
{
    void onSomeEvent();
}

public class bar : foo
{
    void onSomeEvent()
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}

public class baz : foo
{
    void onSomeEvent()
    {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call onSomeEvent() on all instances of `foo` without having an explicit reference to them?

Comment: You can't, because you cannot get a reference to those objects, as explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100812-00/?p=13163). Also, this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Are you looking for events? See [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event)

Comment: @MindSwipe I have multiple instances of different classes that implement an interface. I want to call a method of the interface on all of these instances. For now i solved the problem by using a list and iterating over it, but this means that i have to add each instance to the list every time i create a new one and remove them when they are done.

Comment: `I want to call a method of the interface on all of these instances.` **Why?** Are you trying to build some sort of plugin architecture, or...?